# How to apply a fuction with a range of datetime in KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer

```
let MyFunction = (x:datetime) {
  MyMetrics(x-1d, x)
};
let startDate = datetime(2023-07-15);
let endDate = datetime(2023-07-17);
MyFunction((range timestamp from startDate to endDate step 1))
```

And `MyMetrics(startDate:timestamp, endDate:timestamp)`

I received this error:

```
Error 

 MyFunction(): argument #1 must be a scalar expression
```

Definition for MyMetrics function is below.

```
MyMetrics(startDate:datetime, endDate:datetime) {
let lastweekdata = Events((startofday(startDate) - 8d), (startofday(startDate) - 2d))
| summarize LastWeekAvg = avg(totalCount) by operation, CarType;
 let last1daydata = Events(startofday(startDate)-1d, startofday(startDate))
| summarize LastDayAvg = count() by bin(timestamp, 1d), operation, CarType;
let last1Hourdata = Events(startDate, endDate)
| summarize cnt=count() by operation, CarType, bin(timestamp, 1h) ;
last1Hourdata
| join kind=leftouter last1daydata on CarType, operation
| join kind=leftouter lastweekdata on CarType, operation
```

Comment: you will probably want to update your question with the definition of the `MyMetrics` function. it may impact what you can or can't do, and would help people give you a suitable answer

Comment: @YoniL. I updated the kusto function definition. please have a look.

Comment: Share some sample input data to check more on this. @susanna